# php reading from a file but i take blank input in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, fopen

i am trying to read a file and then i am trying to inserted to mysql table
i have tried the follow and i get the te text and i display the text from the file but when i trying to inserted into the db the row is created but i have nothing inside
any help?

This is my code

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("text.htm", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    echo $line;
    // make the DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=text;';
    $user = 'text';
    $password = 'text';
    $name=$line;
}
try
{   
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    // set the error mode to exception 
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
    PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO text (db_text) 
                   VALUES (:name)';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'PDO Exception Caught.  ';
    echo 'Error with the database: <br />';
    echo 'SQL Query: ', $sql;
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Comment: Debugging 101: `var_dump($name)` right before `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change

`$line = fgets($file_handle);`

to

`$line .= fgets($file_handle);`

inside the while loop.

---

Also, instantiate `$line` with `$line = "";` somewhere before the while-loop;

`fgets` will probably return `false` the last time (or an empty line or something).

Comment: not working mate the . makes it worst and nothing happens with  $line = "";

Comment: `.=` is a concatenation operator. How is it worse? The string is even _more empty_ now? :s

Comment: No , the browser freeze cause it reads a part of the file and the loop makes it reads a little more , and a little more etc etc

Answer (score 0):

try declaring $name before the while... it could be a scope problem....

```
$name = "";    
$file_handle = fopen("text.htm", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    echo $line;
    // make the DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=text;';
    $user = 'text';
    $password = 'text';
    $name=$line;
}
```

Comment: nothing happens but if i remove the first } and put it in the end the data inserted  in my db but for each line in my text i have a new input in my db , so i have 80 rows now